# Find Key (a number) in Field - Mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have problem to search a key in field at the record.

- disProdlist = containt 1 or more key, exp (1,2,3,9,..and so on).

I like to show record which record containt key "9" in the "disProdlist" field.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT disProdName FROM discount WHERE FIND_IN_SET('9','disProdlist');
```

But, it return no result .

So, I try an experiment, I try to changes "disProdlist" to only have one key and its successfully returned the result. But, I want "disProdlist" containt more one keys.

So, anybody can help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Wouldn't this work `SELECT disProdName FROM discount WHERE 'disProdlist' LIKE '%9%;`?  

Btw, `LIKE` can be very slow for large record sets.

Comment: no you would get records with value like '3, 19, 27', that's not what you 're looking for

Comment: 'disProdlist' is a string. `disprodlist` is a column.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   SELECT disProdName FROM discount WHERE FIND_IN_SET('9','1,2,3,9,..and so on');
```

or

```
   SELECT disProdName FROM discount WHERE FIND_IN_SET('9',disProdlist);
```

if disProdlist its a column

[**HERE A DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/419ae/1)

Answer (score 1):

If disProdList is the name of a field, you should not put it in between single quotes in you query.

```
SELECT disProdName FROM discount WHERE FIND_IN_SET('9','disProdlist');
```

This request is incorrect. The second arguement must be a string list (a string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters as stated by the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)).

The correct query is then :

```
SELECT disProdName FROM discount WHERE FIND_IN_SET('9',disProdlist);
```

providing that disProdlist is either a string (VARCHAR, TEXT, ... ) in the correct format or of type [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html)